# Airflow webserver not starting in 1.10

Tags: python, webserver, airflow

Trying to migrate from Airflow 1.9 to Airflow 1.10. After some effort I was able to install the new version but could not load the web UI. When I try to start webserver It  gives an error of file being busy. I have not started any process or operations which might be locking any file. `airflow initdb` works just fine. Error

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/airflow$ airflow webserver
[2018-09-06 18:46:19,916] {settings.py:174} INFO - setting.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=3600
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
[2018-09-06 18:46:20,057] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/

[2018-09-06 18:46:20,156] {logging_config.py:50} INFO - Successfully imported user-defined logging config from airflow.config_templates.airflow_local_settings.DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG
[2018-09-06 18:46:20,750] {models.py:258} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================
[2018-09-06 18:46:22,138] {settings.py:174} INFO - setting.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=3600
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
[2018-09-06 18:46:22 +0000] [26545] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 203, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 198, in run
    self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 139, in start
    self.pidfile.create(self.pid)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/pidfile.py", line 39, in create
    os.rename(fname, self.fname)
OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy
[2018-09-06 18:48:21,760] {cli.py:755} ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds
[2018-09-06 18:48:21,761] {cli.py:756} ERROR - Shutting down webserver
```

Not sure how to resolve this issue. Below is the output of pip freeze

```
adal==1.1.0
alabaster==0.7.11
alembic==0.8.10
amqp==2.3.2
ansible==2.6.3
anyjson==0.3.3
apache-airflow==1.10.0
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==1.6.5
atomicwrites==1.2.1
attrs==18.2.0
Babel==2.6.0
backports-abc==0.5
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5
bcrypt==3.1.4
billiard==3.5.0.4
bleach==2.1.2
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.8.8
botocore==1.11.8
cachetools==2.1.0
celery==4.1.1
certifi==2018.8.24
cffi==1.11.5
cgroupspy==0.1.6
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
colorama==0.3.9
configparser==3.5.0
cookies==2.2.1
coverage==4.5.1
croniter==0.3.25
cryptography==2.3.1
Cython==0.23.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
dicttoxml==1.7.4
dill==0.2.8.2
dnspython==1.15.0
docutils==0.14
ecdsa==0.13
enum34==1.1.6
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
eventlet==0.24.1
Flask==0.12.4
Flask-Admin==1.4.1
Flask-AppBuilder==1.11.1
Flask-Babel==0.11.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Cache==0.13.1
Flask-Caching==1.3.3
Flask-Login==0.2.11
Flask-OpenID==1.2.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
flask-swagger==0.2.13
Flask-WTF==0.14
flower==0.9.2
freezegun==0.3.10
funcsigs==1.0.0
future==0.16.0
futures==3.2.0
gevent==1.3.6
gitdb2==2.0.4
GitPython==2.1.11
google-auth==1.5.1
greenlet==0.4.14
gunicorn==19.7.1
html5lib==1.0.1
httplib2==0.9.1
idna==2.7
imagesize==1.1.0
inflection==0.3.1
ipaddress==1.0.22
iso8601==0.1.12
isort==4.3.4
itsdangerous==0.24
JayDeBeApi==1.1.1
jdcal==1.4
Jinja2==2.8.1
jira==2.0.0
jmespath==0.9.3
JPype1==0.6.3
kombu==4.2.1
kubernetes==7.0.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
ldap3==2.5.1
librabbitmq==2.0.0
linecache2==1.0.0
lockfile==0.12.2
lxml==3.8.0
Mako==1.0.7
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==1.0
mccabe==0.6.1
mock==2.0.0
mongomock==3.11.1
monotonic==1.5
more-itertools==4.3.0
moto==1.1.19
mysqlclient==1.3.13
nose==1.3.7
nose-ignore-docstring==0.2
nose-timer==0.7.3
ntlm-auth==1.2.0
numpy==1.15.1
oauthlib==2.1.0
odfpy==1.3.6
openpyxl==2.5.6
ordereddict==1.1
packaging==17.1
pandas==0.23.4
parameterized==0.6.1
paramiko==2.4.1
pathlib2==2.3.2
pbr==4.2.0
pendulum==1.4.4
pep8==1.7.1
pluggy==0.7.1
protobuf==3.6.1
psutil==4.4.2
psycopg2==2.7.5
psycopg2-binary==2.7.5
py==1.6.0
pyaml==17.12.1
pyasn1==0.4.4
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
pycparser==2.18
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0
pydevd==1.4.0
Pygments==2.2.0
PyJWT==1.6.4
pylint==1.9.3
pymssql==2.1.4
PyNaCl==1.2.1
pyodbc==4.0.24
pyparsing==2.2.0
pysftp==0.2.9
pytest==3.8.0
pytest-cov==2.6.0
python-apt==1.1.0b1+ubuntu0.16.4.2
python-daemon==2.1.2
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-editor==1.0.3
python-nvd3==0.15.0
python-openid==2.2.5
python-slugify==1.2.6
pytz==2018.5
pytzdata==2018.5
pywinrm==0.3.0
PyYAML==3.13
qds-sdk==1.9.9
rednose==1.3.0
requests==2.19.1
requests-mock==1.5.2
requests-ntlm==1.1.0
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.1.13
scandir==1.9.0
sentinels==1.0.0
setproctitle==1.1.10
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.11.0
smmap2==2.0.4
snakebite==2.11.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
Sphinx==1.7.9
sphinx-argparse==0.2.2
Sphinx-PyPI-upload==0.2.1
sphinx-rtd-theme==0.4.1
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.1.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.11
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.33.3
tablib==0.12.1
tabulate==0.7.7
tenacity==4.8.0
termstyle==0.1.11
testfixtures==6.3.0
text-unidecode==1.2
thrift==0.11.0
tornado==5.1
traceback2==1.4.0
typing==3.6.6
tzlocal==1.5.1
unicodecsv==0.14.1
Unidecode==1.0.22
unittest2==1.1.0
urllib3==1.23
vine==1.1.4
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==0.52.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wrapt==1.10.11
WTForms==2.2.1
xlrd==1.1.0
xlwt==1.3.0
xmltodict==0.11.0
zope.deprecation==4.3.0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check using `ps aux | grep gunicorn` and kill all the processes if they are running and then retry running the webserver.

Comment: If I kill the process with kill process it will automatically create a new one. The error remains the same. I need to make some changes around the security and restart the webserver.

Comment: Have you integrated airflow webserver with `systemd` ?  If so you might need to run `sudo systemd stop airflow-webserver`