# How to access UI in Airflow 1.10?

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

To start with I am trying to upgrade from `1.9` version to `1.10` so my setup contains two vms running different versions of airflow with different port forwarding.
I can access UI from vm running with 1.9 but not able to access UI from `1.10`.
To debug I want to confirm if airflow webserver is running. if I execute

> sudo systemctl start airflow-webserver

it throws no error but when
I am looking at `netstat` I am not seeing any process listening to port `8080`(default).

Also I have not created any user as I do not need `rbac` authentication ? Can that be a problem?

As requested by @kaxil. Below is the output of `ps aux | grep airflow`
[image]
Can someone provide some suggestions on how to fix this problem? Also if you need any further resource can provide it. I am not sure what is relevant here.

Output of `journalctl -u airflow-webserver.service -b`

[image]

Comment: Run without systemctl i.e just `airflow webserver` and put the logs you see on the screen.

Comment: @kaxil without systemctl I have another question raised long before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210483/airflow-webserver-not-starting-in-1-10

Comment: Can you give me output of `ps aux | grep airflow`

Comment: @kaxil Edited the post

Comment: Hey @kaxil , I was following some other post with your comment on it to print the output of `journalctl -u airflow-webserver.service -b'. As a matter of fact it gave me an error in ascii encoding. Would that help in order to debug what might be going wrong?

Comment: Yes it would, can you post that

Comment: I edited the post. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Error message shows that there is an issue with `airflow.cfg` file i.e. there might be a character in your `airflow.cfg`  that is causing the issue. Recheck your config file, if you don't find an issue, post your config file in your question and we will try to figure it out.

Comment: It took me a while to find out the problem in the configs. It was a mistake of `'` which was some other symbol in my default config template. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Awesome:-) Can you accept thr answer to help future viewers?